# How to add a .png as a repeating fill for a SVG element

Tags: html, css, svg, element

I am trying to add a repeating .png as the filler for a SVG polygon element that does not scale with the svg responsive width.

I have the .png added as a Pattern and that is now applied to the svg element but the repeated images scale down to a smaller size on mobile. I need the repeated .png images not to scale.

Suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is discussed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns

Comment: That is very close, my issue is that with the page being responsive whe nthe svg size changes the pattern that is placed on the Object is then changed also. I need the pattern on the object not to move at all when the svg is scaled down.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is part of the SVG, it will scale with the SVG.  You cannot avoid that.  SVG2 will probably support non-scaling patterns, but that doesn' help you now.

What you could do is apply the pattern as a background to a `<div>` and use the SVG as a CSS mask applied to that `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks for the information :) I will make it responsive another way then.